# Onclick html attribute invoking encapsulated function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can you call an encapsulated jQuery function using html attribute `onclick="myFunction()"`?

**HTML**

`<input type="submit" onclick="processForm()">`

**Script**

```
(function($) {

    function processForm() {
        alert('You rang?');
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This code `(function($) { ...... })(jQuery);` is called **Closures** which means all the code inside it is not available to the outside world. You need to either make that function global or make sure a global variable points to this function .

Comment: Community has already given you the answers. As a coding standards you need to separate JavaScript and HTML code. so binding the click events inside your jquery is the right way. But for some reason if you really want to use the `onclick` in HTML only then replace your this line `function processForm() {` with `window.processForm = function(){` and then in your HTML `onclick="window.processForm()"` .. Here `window` is a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can change the scope in which you apply your onclick, though :

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit">
```

**JS**

```
(function($) {

    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
      processForm();
    });

    function processForm() {
        alert('You rang?');
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the event and the function in the same scope.

```
 <input type="submit" class="inputTarget">

(function($) {
            $(".inputTarget").on("click",function(){
              processForm();
            });

            function processForm() {
                alert('You rang?');
            }

})(jQuery);
```